# jQuery if one of many inputs has any value, then add a class

Tags: jquery, forms, each

Trying to add a class to a button if there has been any input in one of six text fields on the page. Getting a console error that says "`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'`" referring to my `var val` line.

Syntaxual? Thanks for your help.

HTML:

```
<input id="a" class="answer" type="text">
<input id="b" class="answer" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
var val = $('.answer').each(function(){
    $(this).value();
});

if (/^\s*$/.test(val)){
    $('#theOne').addClass('show');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not `value`:

```
var val = $('.answer').each(function(){
    $(this).val();
});
```

You may have been thinking of the native `value` property (which is probably preferable in terms of efficiency):

```
var val = $('.answer').each(function(){
    this.value;
});
```

However, none of this helps seeing as your `each` loop doesn't actually do anything. You could use `filter` to see if any of your inputs have a value:

```
var inputs = $(".answer").filter(function() {
    return this.value;
});
if(inputs.length) {
    $('#theOne').addClass('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.answer').filter(function(){return $(this).val() != '';}).length) {
   $('#theOne').addClass('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.answer').each(function(){
    $.trim($(this).value()).length>0? $('#theOne').addClass('show') : '';
});
```